# I want to save my progress on a decryption code

Tags: python, encryption, save, combinations, progress

I have a code(Python 3.0) that is set up to run every possible combination of characters listed

```
from itertools import combinations
import hashlib
import os

test1 = 0
test2 = 0
test3 = 0
test4 = 0
test5 = 0
test6 = 0

file = open("/media/pi/AE/Programming/Python/Cicada 3301/Answers.txt", 'a')
char = "`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'zxcbvbnm,./ ~!@#$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}|ASDFGHJKL:ZXCVBNM<>?"
max_length = len(char)

for length in range(1, max_length + 1):
    for test in map(''.join, combinations(char, length)):
        print(test)
        if test1 == "Found":
            print("36 Found")
        if test2 == "Found":
            print("59 Found")
        if test3 == "Found":
            print("d4 Found")
        if test4 == "Found":
            print("46 Found")
        if test5 == "Found":
            print("45 Found")
        if test6 == "Found":
            print("51236 Found")
        hashedmd5 = hashlib.md5(test.encode('utf-8'))
        hashed512 = hashlib.sha512(test.encode('utf-8'))
        #print("md5 = "+hashedmd5.hexdigest())
        #print("sha512 = "+hashed512.hexdigest())
        if hashedmd5.hexdigest() == "36367763ab73783c7af284446c":
            file.write("36367763ab73783c7af284446c"+hashedmd5.hexdigest()+test+"\n")
            test1 = "Found"
        if hashedmd5.hexdigest() == "59466b4cd653239a311cb7116":
            file.write("59466b4cd653239a311cb7116="+hashedmd5.hexdigest()+"="+test+"\n")
            test2 = "Found"
        if hashedmd5.hexdigest() == "d4618dee09a8425893dc7500b":
            file.write("d4618dee09a8425893dc7500b="+hashedmd5.hexdigest()+"="+test+"\n")
            test3 = "Found"
        if hashedmd5.hexdigest() == "464fdaf1672d7bef5e891c6e227":
            file.write("464fdaf1672d7bef5e891c6e227="+hashedmd5.hexdigest()+"="+test+"\n")
            test4 = "Found"
        if hashedmd5.hexdigest() == "4568926a49fb4f45132c2a8b4":
            file.write("4568926a49fb4f45132c2a8b4="+hashedmd5.hexdigest()+"="+test+"\n")
            test5 = "Found"
        if hashed512.hexdigest() == "36367763ab73783c7af284446c59466b4cd653239a311cb7116d4618dee09a8425893dc7500b464fdaf1672d7bef5e891c6e2274568926a49fb4f45132c2a8b4":
            file.write("36367763ab73783c7af284446c59466b4cd653239a311cb7116d4618dee09a8425893dc7500b464fdaf1672d7bef5e891c6e2274568926a49fb4f45132c2a8b4="+hashed512.hexdigest()+"="+test+"\n")
            test6 = "Found"
```

I would like to program it to start on a combination of my choosing and continue from there. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to replace `combinations` (better yet, the entire `map` expression`) with a custom generator that will accept a caller-supplied starting point, and increment the combinations from there.  If you don't know how to write a generator, then now is a very good time to learn: work through those tutorials for this (relatively) easy application.

Then you need to simply upgrade your program to accept that specified starting point and pass it into the generator.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: That helps a little bit. How would I make a generator that excepts a starting point, and gives a similar output to my current generator? Sorry if my question sounds dumb but I'm new to generators.

Comment: That question is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  As I already said, now is the time to work through the intro materials on generators.  Re-read your request: it seems to boil down to "write the code for me", or "adapt that programming concept to my situation".  Stack Overflow is generally for a specific question about code you've written, but doesn't quite work.  Give it a try; if you get blocked, post your [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  **That** is where SO helps you to finish the job.

Comment: Ok! Still figuring out SO as well! Thanks!